# react material ui grow on left side

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to make the context menu open not in the center of the button, but to the left of the button? With using properties Material UI.

Working example from link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/2f33z

Now this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Here is a link to an example from the documentation:
https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#menulist-composition

```js
  <div>
    <Button
      ref={anchorRef}
      aria-controls={open ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
      aria-haspopup="true"
      onClick={handleToggle}
    >
      Toggle Menu Grow
    </Button>
    <Popper open={open} anchorEl={anchorRef.current} role={undefined} transition disablePortal>
      {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
        <Grow
          {...TransitionProps}
          style={{ transformOrigin: placement === 'bottom' ? 'center top' : 'center bottom' }}
        >
          <Paper>
            <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
              <MenuList autoFocusItem={open} id="menu-list-grow" onKeyDown={handleListKeyDown}>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
              </MenuList>
            </ClickAwayListener>
          </Paper>
        </Grow>
      )}
    </Popper>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's actually not clear what you want. Please add more information to the question, what you've tried to achieve it and remove the off-topic stuff at the end.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden, really, sorry, just created a post yesterday late at night and was very tired. Reworked the post, now it's as clear as possible what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Popper` component should have a `placement` property of value `bottom-start`:

```
// ...
<Popper
  placement="bottom-start"
  // ...
>
// ...
```

For more options look here: https://material-ui.com/components/popper/#positioned-popper.